# Advice with powershell script syntax

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script to perform the following:

Within a folder `Folder > Subfolder1 > Subfolder2` there are 30+ `subfolders.zip`in which there is another subfolder with 200 HRML files.
I would like to search for a keyword `WTSE` in the HTML files and any files containing such keyword would be moved to another folder.

My script looks as follows at the moment:

```
Get-childitem C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Folder\ -filter *.html -recurse | select-string 'WTSE'|foreach-object -process{move-item} C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Folder2`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to guess what you mean and edited the question accordingly. For more guidance, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. The problem is with the part after `ForEach-Object`.

Since you are not searching for a string using regex, I would suggest adding the `-SimpleMatch` to the `Select-String` cmdlet.

Try below:

```
$sourceFolder = 'C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Folder'
$destination  = 'C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Folder2'

(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter '*.html' -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'WTSE' -SimpleMatch) | 
    Move-Item -Destination $destination
```

The [Move-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7#parameters) cmdlet can take an array of paths and these can also accepts pipeline input, so there is no need to use `ForEach-Object` here.

<sup>Note I'm using brackets around the first part `(Get-ChildItem ... -SimpleMatch)`. This prevents the error that the process cannot open the file because it is in use</sup>

Comment: Dude you're a freaking legend, it worked, thanks a bunch man! The only issue I have at the moment is it doesn't work when the folder path is too long like for example 'C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\DailyReport\2017\May\reports' I have faced this issue a number of times when writing scripts, it just doesn't seem to work, I am not sure why. The script runs, but there is no change or action taken.